# How to identify a transaction table?

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

i have database that has **master** tables prefixed with `mt_` and **transactions** tables prefixed with `tr_` . But when i go through the database i started to wonder what is the actual definition of a transaction table and master table. To my understanding transaction table should have a composite primary key (primary key made from two or many PKs of other tables). But when i looked at the transaction tables in database, there are tables that have the composite key as mentioned previously also it has tables tagged as tr_ but have only one key tagged as PK and they also have PK keys that belongs to other tables but they weren't even tagged as FK...

So could any one here explain the difference between a master table and a transaction table and how to identify them in DB?

**Updated** 
Here is an examtple of my db

**tr_orders**

```
OrderId int PK
CustomerId int Fk
OrderDate datetime  etc
```

**tr_reciept**

```
RecieptId int PK
OrderId int **(but not FK)**
PaindAmount money
recieptDate datetime
```

Here are the table structure of the complete two tables:

**tr_orders**

[image]

**tr_reciept**

[image]

i dont understand why these tables are **tr** tables?

Comment: Generally speaking a transaction table has a date in it and usually a numeric value. It usually contains one or more _foreign keys_ to master tables. The PK should define the uniqueness of the table which may or may not be a unique combination of master tables. Usually it doesn't, especially for example when there is a date involved.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Is it possible to show me an example of this?

Comment: The term 'transaction' is pretty loose. But I can give it a go

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid if i could see a sample it would great cus the database i have doesn't have a consistency...

Comment: I've posted some info but it would help if you described some tables in more detail.

Comment: They both have dates. They both describe an 'event'. They are transaction tables. A 'master' table would be Customer, Location etc. where you go off and look up the Customer and there's a whole host of attributes attached to that customer.

Comment: Whats confusing you is that they are a 'master-detail' relationship. They are many to one. There are 0,1 or many receipts per order. So you take an order for an amount on a date - that's a transaction. Then afterwards you receive receipts on an a date for an amount (a transaction against the original order). This is an example of master-detail transactions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Why you don't always put a Primary Key on all the Foreign Keys*

When something 'happens' it goes into a transaction. Someone buys a toy at a shop. A row is created recording that it was a toy and the datetime it happened and how much it cost.

The someone else buys a toy ten minutes later

We have two records in our transaction table:

```
Date          Time     Product_Key     Shop_Key    Amount
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
18 Dec 2015   13:05    7                12           10
18 Dec 2015   13:15    7                12           10
```

Here we have two foreign keys: `Product_Key` and `Shop_Key`

We can't create a PK on just those two foreign keys because then one shop could only ever sell one toy.

So the PK does not automatically go on all the FK's

But *really* the thing to take away is that your data model (tables, fields, keys, datatypes) reflects what your business does. If a shop could truly only ever sell one toy, it would be a valid data model to have a PK on those two fields.

*Some characteristics of 'transactional vs master tables*

"Transactional" and "master" tables generally have a many to one relationship, meaning many transactions match one master record. Many purchase records match the same single toy record. A FK is a dead giveaway to this kind of relationship although "master" tables also have FK's

"Transactional" tables usually have a date or some kind of event id and are often 'aggregated' when reporting. This could be a record count or a sum of an amount.

*Some characteristics of real world systems*

It's entirely likely that someone forgot to put on a FK or PK, or it could be that there is a unique key (not a PK) enforcing what you are expectig to see.

I've seen live systems where the keys were clearly incorrect, or there were no keys at all.

Comment: i have updated my original post with a sample two tables in my DB!

Comment: can you also take look at the link becuase i have posted this on C# corner http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/thread/330184/how-to-identify-a-transaction-table.aspx

Comment: I totally disagree with the comment on that site. EMP is *not* a transaction table. It _does_ have a many to one relationship like a transaction table but it does not have a 'time' component such as transaction date or event date or ID. It's not recording transactions (events over time). It's a master table.

Comment: that exactly my confusion by definition transaction table is like you said one with datetime column but in my DB the so called master tables and transaction tables are tagged exactly as what that was posted on c-sharp corner... may be its a wrong naming convention used for tables like Emp tables

Comment: Perhaps you could post the DDL for the confusing table.

Comment: i have updated the original post with what i can post

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> Master - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - Transaction
>
> Country .... Employeee ...... Customer ........... Order
> ```

Master & Lookup tables exist in a Range, not a Binary On/Off State, and reflects the expectation of the amount of activity the table will experience

Lookup/Reference tables like State, Currency, Country, etc. RARELY have new records or changes -- Very "Master"

Employees add or change records occasionally, but not often (hopefully) so more "Master" than "Transaction"

Customers add or change records more often than Employees (also hopefully) so still a measure of "Master" but also with "Transaction" qualities

Orders are added and changed ALL the time (hopefully) and are Very "Transaction,"
Same with Reciepts

If a table has No FK fields, it's likely very "Master"

Tables with FKs have some amount of "Transaction" to them, the more you expect new records - the more "Transaction" the table could be.

Keys:

in my opinion, every table should have a surrogate PK, not related to FKs or any Natural keys.  Lots of reasons for this opinion, but whatever works for you is cool, too.

Often, if there is an obvious Natural key, then a table needs a Unique constraint for that key, in addition to the PK