How to identify Transaction tables within a SQL database?
I need to identify which tables within a sql database are transactional, in order to diferentiate whether the load will be full or incremental in Azure Data Factory moving data into a parquet file in ADLS Gen 2. Unfortunately, any prefixes or string wildcards would not help identifying them by name. Any suggestions on how to proceed/start from somewhere will be greatly valued.
I tried counting the rows of the tables just to check if the row count is greater than (let's say 1 million rows) such that the tables with that feature will be incrementally loaded. But I need to find any transaction tables as well.

A transaction table will likely have foreign keys, status flags,  and dates. A definition table will have descriptions and active bits. see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34348193/how-to-identify-a-transaction-table

More often than not such an analysis is conducted on the client application by looking at what data it handles and how the UI is structured. But most important, why does it matters?

Why not ask the owner of the tables?

I think you use SQL Server (the tag t-sql refer to SQL Server or Sybase).
The "transactional behaviour" that you think as "level" (Full, Bulk Logged, simple) is done at the database level not at the table level...
The query to know that is the following :
SELECT name, recovery_model_desc 
FROM   sys.databases;

To be clear all database ar transactional, and there is no way to avoid transaction in SQL Server... But the level you speak about is in fact, the way the transaction log receive data and manage itself.
In the "SIMPLE" mode, the transaction log receive the minimal information to do transactions and is truncated at the moment of the new data (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, ...) are reported from the memory (data are cached) by the CHECHKPOINT mecanism to the storage data files.
In the "BULK MODE" mode, the transaction log receive the minimal information to do transactions and is never truncated until a BACKUP LOG is done.
In the "FULL" mode, the the transaction log receive the maximal information to do transactions and is never truncated until a BACKUP LOG is done.
In "FULL" recovery model, AlwaysOn can be used and PITR restaurations are possible.
In "BULK" recovery model, AlwaysOn cannot be used but PITR restaurations are possible.
In "SIMPLE" recovery model, AlwaysOn cannot be used not PITR restaurations are possible.
